# Java build path configure

Tags: eclipse

how to solve java build path problem in eclipse instead of JRE System Library there is "Modulepath and Classpath" only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modulepath and Classpath are normal for Java 9 and later.

To add a JRE click the Modulepath entry. You should then be able to click 'Add Library...'. In the dialog that pops up select 'JRE System Library' and click Next. You should then be able to select a JRE to use.

Note: The New Java Project wizard should have set this up during project creation. It is not clear from your question why this didn't happen.